# Can i update a Contact record with details from a Contract record using Visual Workflow?

Tags: visual-workflow

When I update a field 'Description' on a Contract record which is under an Account 'acc', I want to populate a field 'Description' on all the Contacts under acc. Is this possible using Visual Workflow ?

Comment: I know that this can be done by trigger and i tried process builder, which didn't seem to work. Would like to know if this is possible using visual workflow, before i proceed to write a trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do it with a Process, or with a Flow, or with an Apex trigger. The Process is simplest.

To build a Process to do this, start from Contract. Establish your action criteria nodes, then add an Immediate Action. Select Update Records, then navigate through the Account node to "Contacts" (under the Account). Select that entry.

Configure your field update (which can include references to fields on the Contract) and you're good to go. Here's what the Update Records action looks like.

[image]